# Regex to replace tags in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url

I am using the PHP and Regex below to search through a huge string for

```
[LINK]www.anyurl.com[/LINK]
```

and replace it with:

```
<a href="http://www.anyurl.com">http://www.anyurl.com</a>
```

The http:// is prepended if http or ftp do not exist in front of the url already.

```
$re = '/\[LINK]((?:(?!(http|ftp)|\[\/LINK]).)*)\[\/LINK]/i'; 
$subst = '[LINK]http://$1[/LINK]'; 
$xtext = preg_replace($re, $subst, $xtext, 1);
$xtext = preg_replace("/(\[LINK\])(\S*)(\[\/LINK])/", "<a href=\"$2\" target='_blank'>$2</a>", $xtext);
```

My problem is it only appears to be working for the first match it comes to and not other `[LINK]www.urls.com[/LINK]` in the document. The document being `$xtext`

Comment: I am none the wiser now but thanks for commenting

Comment: To expound on @j_mcnally [regex is not for everything](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jbroadway/2836900

Comment: @MikeC, Regex for parsing HTML is considered bad practice. Hence the `NO NO NO`. The obvious reason is any HTML tag can have more HTML tags inside.

Comment: @developerwjk I am not parsing HTML tags. When did [LINK] [/LINK] become a HTML tag?

Comment: @MikeC people here can be ignorant and just regex haters.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I wouldn't mind but they could provide a solution rather than just saying what they say. The solution I have above is fast and works well but i need it to repeat. I expect those that attack don't actually understand what they are seeing.

Comment: I'm not sure that `(\S*)` is correct. Wouldn't that just capture spaces?

Comment: It works fine as is, no problem with the current regex but I need it to continue through and find any other links in the document. No (\S*) capture any non whitespace character

Comment: Could some of your data be URL encoded but looks correct in a browser?

Comment: No i can do a var_dump on $xtext and the [LINK]urls[/LINK] exist

Comment: I'd post some sample data from $xtext in the question.

Comment: PHP has a [BBCode built-in extension](http://php.net/book.bbcode).

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, I have just found my error and it is so simple. In my third line:

```
$xtext = preg_replace($re, $subst, $xtext, 1);
```

I have 1 at the end of the preg_replace i.e. replace once. This should be set to -1 or left blank to replace all.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be the greedyness of your first regex. As you prepend the http:// to your first found link, all other links will stay the same. So please try (note the additional questionmark in line one):

```
$re = '/\[LINK]((?:(?!(http|ftp)|\[\/LINK]).)*?)\[\/LINK]/i'; 
$subst = '[LINK]http://$1[/LINK]'; 
$xtext = preg_replace($re, $subst, $xtext);
$xtext = preg_replace("/(\[LINK\])(\S*)(\[\/LINK])/", "<a href=\"$2\" target='_blank'>$2</a>", $xtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first expression the 1 needed to be removed, as you already figured out.  Notice the second expression is the same as your second expression but with `*` replaced with `+?`, and the unnecessary capture groups around the tags removed. `*` doesn't stop at the first `[\LINK]` but at the last one, resulting in a link with display text like `http://www.google.com[/LINK]\n[LINK]http://www.yahoo.com` so `+?` is needed.

```
$xtext = '[LINK]www.google.com[/LINK]\n[LINK]www.yahoo.com[/LINK]';

$re = '/\[LINK]((?:(?!(http|ftp)|\[\/LINK]).)*)\[\/LINK]/i';
$subst = '[LINK]http://$1[/LINK]';
$xtext = preg_replace($re, $subst, $xtext, 1);

$xtext = preg_replace("/\[LINK\](\S+?)\[\/LINK]/", "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>", $xtext);
```

Comment: You are not checking if the link has http or ftp prepended to it in the first place. Mine checks if the link is [LINK]www.example.com[/LINK] or [LINK]http://www.example.com[/LINK] and if it is the former prepends http:// to it.

Comment: @developerwjk Your expression substituting my (\S*) for your (\S+?) takes 58 iterations while mine takes 32. I'll stick with mine. I don't see where you have rationalised the capture groups in your example??? Anyway I solved the issue, you started off abusive, have given me 2 incorrect answers so we will leave it there.

Comment: @MikeC, Abusive? I was explaining j_mcnally's comment.